# Soft body not staying contained in rigid body

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision, soft-body

I am fairly new to all this but I have been trying to do a motion graphic of a (balloon-like) soft body inflating and staying contained in a rigid body (cage). I have set the inside sphere to 'soft body' and the outer sphere/cage to 'collision'. Yet the soft body extends further than the cage and they don't interact at all. If someone could help me with my problem it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Collision > Softbody and Cloth > Inner, can you consider whether it is appropriate

Comment: if you include the blend file in your post doing a troubleshooting would be much easier. My first impression is that you may have to turn on face collision for your softbody, and increase it's vertex amount. Further the Thickness values of the Collision object in your case should be like Outer > Inner. A thickness value of 0.2 is equal to 20 cm.